# Consistency of Area Axioms

Tags: measure-theory

If we want to calculate area of an triangle or equivalently want to calcuate area under curve y=x (x∈[0,1]), we can use two methods: 1)- Assuming we know the area of the square, we can translate the triangle, completing square and divide it by 2. OR 2)-we can use Riemann integral. Similarly, we can calculate area under curve y=x2 (x∈[0,c]) by thinking it equivalent to volume of a special pyramide. By constructing a pyramide whose base is a square and dimensions (c,c) and whose height is c, it's clear, if we go down from top of it by x unit, cross-sectional area is x2. Volume of this pyramide can be calculated by completing it with some other similar pyramides to cube (c,c,c) by only translations and without using limit concept (related to Cavaliarie's assumption). And also the volume is, as you may know, c3/3. This value is identical to riemann integral of y=x2 (x∈[0,c]). My question is, why are these two methods equivalent? More specifically, how do we know that, if we use those area axioms not involving limit concept and compute a specific area, it would be equal to the area value computed by using the area axioms involving limit concept. I think this question is about consistency of area axioms. This is intuitively clear, but I need formal proof... Actually some of the areas under specific curves can be calculated exactly without using riemann integral by using only translations, addition etc. But every time I calculated a Riemann integral for a specific area, I ask myself, maybe, I would find another value if I managed to calculate the area by another method? Sincerely.

Comment: As to area axioms, can you give a list or a reference ?

Comment: I think the following is appropriate... http://www.math.ku.edu/~jmartin/courses/math409-S13/axioms-short.pdf I think that, my question is about consistency of Axiom 19 with Axiom 16-17-18... I mean, you can use Cavaliarie principle to calculate the volume of a pyramide (Axiom 16-17-18 suffices) or you can also use the integral methods (I think related to Axiom 19) to calculate it. But we arrive at same value... Why?

Comment: Let me give you an example... Assume we want to calculate the area under the curve of the parabola x^2 between [0, 1]. We don't what the area is (definition), but we assume that we can add the areas (axiom). So let's divide the parabola by half and add those two pieces. It's clear that now it can be described as A(0, 1/2): x^2 + (x+1/2)^2 = A(0, 1/2): 2x^2 + x + 1/4. In addition, if we rotate the parabola by 90 degree, it can be represented again like this: A(0, 1/2) 8x^2. In latter case, we use inverse function. So by axioms, rotation doesn't change area

Comment: then  A(0, 1/2)2x^2 + A(0,1/2)x + A(0,1/2)1/4 = A(0, 1/2) 8x^2. We know that A(0,1/2)x is a triangle and A(0,1/2)1/4 is a square. So we can calculate them. Then,

Comment: Then,                                     A(0, 1/2)2x^2 + 1/8 + 1/8 = A(0, 1/2) 8x^2. We can add or substract areas so  "6 A(0,1/2)x^2 = 2/8 . And finally A(0,1/2)x^2 = 1/24. That is the exact result of riemann integral. But I didn't use any limit concept. Only rotation, addition, inverse function and Cavalieri principle. But why are they equivalent?

Comment: How do you find the area of a circle by area axioms ?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way to calculate it without using limit concept. But I'm interested in such cases, in which the area of interest is a region under a curve (not a line), but area can be calculated by simple means (like above)...

Comment: In your reference I don't see Cavalieri's principle $\dots$

Comment: Ok you're right, but what are your suggestions about my question?

Comment: One should prove that the area function is **unique** and **just** the Riemann integral. [Here](http://www.math.sunysb.edu/~eitan/riemann.pdf) the situation is similar.

Comment: As far as I understand, you say that, it is possible to convert the steps in my method into integral language... It seems reasonable, because I use addition and rotation, but we know that integral is additive and also there is a Fubini theorem (for rotation)... Is it right?

Comment: I referred to the FTC for a non negative continuous function on a compact interval. From the axioms one deduces that the area function of the undergraph is an antiderivative.